# Finding all elements(which are integer) in an array whose sum is equals to the element exists within the array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to locate all integer elements in an array, whose sum is equal to one of the integer elements within the array.

For example, let's assume I have an array like this as input:
`[1, 2, 4, 10, 90, 302, 312, 500]`

Then output should have all integer elements including the integer element which is sum of other elements. It will be like: `[10, 302, 312]` i.e. `10+302 = 312`

This is what I tried in ruby:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 4, 10, 90, 302, 312, 500]
numbers.each_with_index do |number, index|
  target = []
  return [] if numbers.size < 3
  target << number
  puts "target in numbers.each: #{target.inspect}"
  0.upto(numbers.size).each do |i|
    puts "target in (index+1).upto: #{target.inspect}"
    target << numbers[i] unless index == i
    next if target.size < 2
    break if target.inject(&:+) > numbers.max
    puts "== array starts =="
    puts [target, target.inject(&:+)].flatten.inspect if numbers.include? target.inject(&:+)
    puts "== array ends =="
  end
end
```

But it's not making expected output. I'll update if I get any luck on this. Till then can anyone point out that what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

An algorithm will be good for me as well.

Comment: [10, 302, 312] sum is nowhere inside your array.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain in more detail how `[10,302,312]` is the desired output?

Comment: I think it is because 10 + 302 = 312.

Comment: Yes, @zwippie. You're correct. it's 10+302 = 312. and hence output is:  `[10, 302, 312]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation:

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 10, 90, 302, 312, 500]

(2..arr.count).each do |len|
  arr.combination(len).each do |comb|
    sum = comb.inject(:+)
    if arr.include? sum
      puts (comb << sum).inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

zwippie's answer with small changes..

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 10, 90, 302, 312, 500]
result = []
(2..arr.count-1).to_a.each do |len|
  arr.combination(len).to_a.each do |comb|
    sum = comb.inject(:+)
    if arr.include? sum
      result << (comb << sum)
    end
  end
end
result
```